# haproxy http frontend , backend

Tags: http, haproxy, port-80

I need to use haproxy for listening to port 80 and forward the request if it matches the role for that I did this this but I don't know how I can tell to use the prober back end

```
frontend httpfw
bind *:80
mode http
acl # what I must write here to defend a domain like test1.com
acl # what I must write here to defend a domain like test2.com

use_backend httptest1 if # how can I told to use this backend if the request comes from test1.com
use_backend httptest2 if # how can I told to use this backend if the request come from test2.com

backend httptest1
mode http
balance source
server httptest1 1.1.1.1:80 



backend httptest2
mode http
balance source
server httptest2 2.2.2.2:80
```

Thanks :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following should route traffic to the respective backends, in the example you provided:

```
## Look at host header
acl host_test1 hdr(host) -i test1.com
acl host_test2 hdr(host) -i test2.com

## figure out which one to use depending on the criteria above
use_backend httptest1 if host_test1
use_backend httptest2 if host_test2
```